# ASP.NET MVC Data Annotation Regular Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble to get a regex to work

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Challonge URL")]
    [RegularExpression(@"http://challonge.com/[a-zA-Z0-9]{1-20}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid challonge URL")]
    public string Challonge_URL { get; set; }
```

The input http://challonge.com/56h9ezkf is not valid when it should be, is there something wrong with the regular expression?

Comment: How are you using this? With client-side validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are several things...

- you need to escape `/` and `.` using `\` because slash and dot mean things in regex and you want to match them literally
- it's `{1,20}`, not `{1-20}`
- you should probably add `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end so it matches the entire string; otherwise garbage at the beginning or end of the URL will be considered valid

`^http:\/\/challonge\.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}$`